# Combining 2 records with the same column value from the same table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I combine two records, which have the same column? For example, given the `parent` column value for two records is same, I want to combine these two. This is not possible with `GROUP BY` as it will only return one record.

The task has to be achieved in Rails.

Comment: What does it mean to "club" a record?

Comment: club as in join them...

so like if u have a record `message` = abc, `parent` = 1 and another as `message` = `xyz` and `parent` = 1 then i want to get the 2 of them in such a manner that i can make a string like message1 + message2

Comment: Say "join" then. "Club" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ah, "club" means to "join them", as in "Amit has randomly decided to change the meaning of the word 'club'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a table `messages` with this structure and data:

```
id  parent_id  message
--  ---------  -------
1   42         Foo
2   42         Bar
```

Then you can make this SQL query:

```
    SELECT a.message AS message1, 
           b.message AS message2
      FROM messages a
INNER JOIN messages b ON a.parent_id=b.parent_id
     WHERE a.id<b.id;
```

And get this result:

```
message1 message2
-------- --------
Foo      Bar
```

You need to ensure that the `a.id` and `b.id` are not the same so that you don't get the results `"Foo Foo"` and `"Bar Bar"`, and you also need to order them unless you want both `"Foo Bar"` and `"Bar Foo"` results.

You can also choose to perform the string concatenation directly in your query. Different RDBMS use different syntax for this; for MySQL I believe it would be:

```
SELECT concat(a.message, b.message) AS clubbed_message
       ...
```

*(For completeness, MSSQL uses the `+` operator for string concatenation, and PostgreSQL and SQLite use the `||` operator.)*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the best option is to query for all them and concatenate them in Ruby land.

Something like:

```
Model.where(:parent => 1).collect(&:message).join
```